# R new variable based on other column

Tags: r

Using the dataset 'cars' in R I would like to add a new column to this dataset that takes the average of the column 'dist' dependent on the values in the column 'speed', while also having R evaluating the 'speed' as a grouping parameter.

So first I need 19 groups reflecting the unique speeds in cars$speed:

```
4  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25
```

For each of these 19 groups I would like to know what the average dist is, but only if at least one of the entries in each of these 19 categories meet a criteria (e.g. at least one dist-value is above 20.

With the cars-dataset I would get something like this back for the cars with speed 4 to 12:

```
speed   dist    avr_dist_if_one_speed_is_above20
4   2   none
4   10  none
7   4   13
7   22  13
8   16  none
9   10  none
10  18  26
10  26  26
10  34  26
11  17  22.5
11  28  22.5
12  14  21.5
12  20  21.5
12  24  21.5
12  28  21.5
...
```

Since the 2 cars that have speed 4 both have a dist below 20, I do not get an average for these two entries. For the cars that have speed 7 I get an average dist of 13 since at least one car with speed 7 have a dist above 20.

For the cars with speed 8 and 9 I do not get an average, as both of these cars have a dist below 20. The cars with speed 10 should return an average of 26

since two of the cars with speed 10 have a dist above 20.

For cars with speed 11 I get 22.5

For cars with speed 12 I get 21.5.

The R-code should calculate an average dist for all the remaining speed-categories, as the rest all include cars with dist>20.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service.  Please add the code you wrote while attempting to solve this yourself.

Comment: For grouping by some column you can take a look at `dplyr` and / or `data.table`.  If you google about grouping and summarizing in R, you will likely find your answer on Stackoverflow quickly.

Comment: I apologize in advance. I am very new to R, and have very little understanding of coding. There is no code for the example above. I generated the output by hand.

Comment: Well your honesty is appreciated.  I would get started learning R by reading the [Intro to R manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html)

Comment: @swk Just to clarify, you want the same number of rows in the output with `avr_dist_if_one_speed_is_above20` duplicated, is that correct (that is what you are showing but I wanted to confirm) ?  The alternative is to output a summary data.frame with `speed` and `avr_dist_if_one_speed_is_above20`.

Comment: I did not know about the dplyr and data.table packages. Thanks for showing me what these are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you are looking for if I understand your question right.

```r
library(dplyr)
    
cars %>%
  group_by(speed) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), avg_dist = ifelse(any(dist > 20),mean(dist, na.rm = T), NA)
```

Comment: Given how the output is displayed by the OP, you would want to use `mutate` and not summarize. The OP shows the new column added to the input data.

Comment: true.  I answered this before the format change so I was going off the description that OP wanted it grouped by speed.

Comment: I edited your code and added a 'match', to fuse it with the original cars dataframe. Like this: library(dplyr)
cars2 <-cars
temp.df.cars2 <- collect(cars %>%
                           group_by(speed) %>%
                           summarise(n = n(),
                                     avg_dist = ifelse(any(dist > 20),mean(dist, na.rm = T), NA)))
cars2 <-cars
cars2$avg_dist <- temp.df.cars2$avg_dist[match(cars2$speed,temp.df.cars2$speed)]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 library(dplyr)

 cars %>% 
       group_by(speed, dist) %>% 
       group_by(speed) %>% 
       mutate(avr_dist_if_one_speed_is_above20 = mean(dist[max(dist)>20]))
```